# Visual Studio XAML Design Window Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a UserControl that I am trying to use in a WPF application. It is a dll that takes a text string, converts it to a shape and renders the shape. Sort of a custom textblock that can be stroked, filled, etc as a shape. I can use it in my project just fine, for a while. Then, it stops showing the control in the design window and I get the Object reference error. If I build and run the project, the control works. Only the design window seems to have a problem with it. This is the code for the control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ComponentCustomControls
{
public class ExtendedTextBlock : Shape
{
    private Geometry _textGeometry;

    #region Dependency Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginPointProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Origin", typeof(Point), typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontSize, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStretchProperty = TextElement.FontStretchProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextElement.FontStretchProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontStyleProperty = TextElement.FontStyleProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontStyle, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnPropertyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FontWeightProperty = TextElement.FontWeightProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SystemFonts.MessageFontWeight, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, OnPropertyChanged));

    #endregion

    #region Property Accessors
    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(PointConverter))]
    public Point Origin
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(OriginPointProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OriginPointProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Font)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontFamilyConverter))]
    public FontFamily FontFamily
    {
        get { return (FontFamily)GetValue(FontFamilyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontFamilyProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontSizeConverter))]
    [Localizability(LocalizationCategory.None)]
    public double FontSize
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontStretchConverter))]
    public FontStretch FontStretch
    {
        get { return (FontStretch)GetValue(FontStretchProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStretchProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontStyleConverter))]
    public FontStyle FontStyle
    {
        get { return (FontStyle)GetValue(FontStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(FontWeightConverter))]
    public FontWeight FontWeight
    {
        get { return (FontWeight)GetValue(FontWeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FontWeightProperty, value); }
    }

    [Bindable(true), Category("Appearance")]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    static ExtendedTextBlock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedTextBlock)));
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return _textGeometry ?? Geometry.Empty; }
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ExtendedTextBlock)d).CreateTextGeometry();
    }

    private void CreateTextGeometry()
    {
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch), FontSize, Brushes.Black);
        _textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(Origin);
    }

    }
}
```

The design window doesn't crash, just shows gray box with the error in it for each instance of the control. If I make a new Project and copy everything over, it shows in the design window again. For a while. Then does the same error again. I can not identify anything I am doing that would cause the change. One minute it's working, next minute it doesn't anymore. Doesn't seem to matter if there's one instance of the control, or 30.

I've seen some answers that say to Debug the XdesProc in another instance of VS. Tried that and get no errors.

Can anybody tell me what is happening here or where to find a solution for this strange issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try to put in Trace.Writeline statments in these three methods to see what the values are:

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get { return _textGeometry ?? Geometry.Empty; }
}

private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((ExtendedTextBlock)d).CreateTextGeometry();
}

private void CreateTextGeometry()
{
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(Text, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, new Typeface(FontFamily, FontStyle, FontWeight, FontStretch), FontSize, Brushes.Black);
    _textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(Origin);
}
```

Then I'd start thinking about how to figure out what the TypeConvertors are up to.

I once used MsgBox.ShowDialog() to debug issues very similar, it pops up a message (even in design time) if put in proper place in code.

Comment: Not getting any information from this answer. Nothing pops up using MsgBox and no output to output window using WriteLIne statements. They do come up at runtime, not at design time. Just to reiterate, the problem exists only at design time. the code compiles and runs fine. Also, a new solution with this code added works at design time for a short while (half an hour or so), before blowing up. What would change after a half an hour or so that would stop this from working correctly (in design mode)?

Comment: I feel your pain, sorry those were the only ideas on had on the matter.  Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: After more messing, I thought it might be the _textGeometry that was null, only the first time, before any dependency properties were changed and the textGeometry was regenerated in CreateTextGeometry(), but everywhere I checked for that it was never null as far as I could tell. Still working on it. Thanks for weighing in, at least.

Comment: I stopped doing this many years ago : new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0)  initializing the data in the DP.  I found doing it in the CTOR was far better for me.  I had nothing but problems doing it in the DP.